# Data Not being inserted into Database from Text Fields

Tags: c#, sql, database, t-sql

So i am trying to make a inventory management web app using asp.net web forms,
I have fought for about three hours to get this code to connect with the database,
Upon doing so it now seems that the text from the text entry fields in my web app is not getting passed to the database, I currently have no idea whats stopping it.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //'" + ItemTextBox.Text + "','" + BrandTextBox.Text + "','" + CostTextBox.Text + "','" + PriceTextBox.Text + "'" + ColourTextBox.Text + "'" + SizeTextBox.Text + "'" + QuantityTextBox.Text + ")", con
        con.Open();
        string sqlquery = "insert into [Project_X_Or] (Item,Brand,Cost,Price,Colour,Size,Quantity) values (@Item,@Brand,@Cost,@Price,@Colour,@Size,@Quantity)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Item Name**********
        string Item = ItemTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item", Item);
        //Brand Of Product**********
        string Brand = BrandTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Brand", Brand);
        //Cost Of Item From Supplier**********
        string Cost = CostTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cost", Cost);
        //Price Of Item When Sold With Design**********
        string Price = PriceTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", Price);
        //Colour Of Product**********
        string Colour = ColourTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Colour", Colour);
        //Size of Product (T-Shirts, Hoodies)**********
        string Size = SizeTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Size", Size);
        //Quantity Of Product In Stock**********
        string Quantity = QuantityTextBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", Quantity);
        con.Close();


        string result = "Added  " + Item + " " + Brand + " " + Cost + " " + Cost + " " + Price + " " + Colour + " " + Size + " " + Quantity;

        resultLabel.Text = result;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemTextBox.Text))
        {
            resultLabel.Text=("Enter Item Into Item Field");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QuantityTextBox.Text))
        {
            resultLabel.Text = ("Enter Amount Into Quantity Field");
        }
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(""))
        //    {
        //    resultLabel2.Text = ("Please Fill Out Fields Above");
        //}


        ItemTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        BrandTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        CostTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        PriceTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        ColourTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        SizeTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        QuantityTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: You're executing the command before you've assigned the parameter values, so it's running without parameters. Move `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` to after you have added the parameters, but before the `con.Close()`

Comment: Oh, Damn it must be the tiredness setting in, i dont know why i didnt see that.

Comment: met with this error now String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: ignore the above my columns were set to char (10) alter command to change it

Answer (score 0):

you should `Execute` after adding `Paramter`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //'" + ItemTextBox.Text + "','" + BrandTextBox.Text + "','" + CostTextBox.Text + "','" + PriceTextBox.Text + "'" + ColourTextBox.Text + "'" + SizeTextBox.Text + "'" + QuantityTextBox.Text + ")", con
    con.Open();
    string sqlquery = "insert into [Project_X_Or] (Item,Brand,Cost,Price,Colour,Size,Quantity) values (@Item,@Brand,@Cost,@Price,@Colour,@Size,@Quantity)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);

    //Item Name**********
    string Item = ItemTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item", Item);
    //Brand Of Product**********
    string Brand = BrandTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Brand", Brand);
    //Cost Of Item From Supplier**********
    string Cost = CostTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Cost", Cost);
    //Price Of Item When Sold With Design**********
    string Price = PriceTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", Price);
    //Colour Of Product**********
    string Colour = ColourTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Colour", Colour);
    //Size of Product (T-Shirts, Hoodies)**********
    string Size = SizeTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Size", Size);
    //Quantity Of Product In Stock**********
    string Quantity = QuantityTextBox.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Quantity", Quantity);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();


    string result = "Added  " + Item + " " + Brand + " " + Cost + " " + Cost + " " + Price + " " + Colour + " " + Size + " " + Quantity;

    resultLabel.Text = result;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemTextBox.Text))
    {
        resultLabel.Text=("Enter Item Into Item Field");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(QuantityTextBox.Text))
    {
        resultLabel.Text = ("Enter Amount Into Quantity Field");
    }
    //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(""))
    //    {
    //    resultLabel2.Text = ("Please Fill Out Fields Above");
    //}


    ItemTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    BrandTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    CostTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    PriceTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    ColourTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    SizeTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    QuantityTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
}
```